# How can I transform string property in Maven pom before using it value?

Tags: maven, properties, maven-plugin

I have artifactId of my Maven module. And I want use it for setting value of Main class in build plugin.

But I need transform value of artifactId, before using it.

For instance:

```
<artifactId>some-usefull-module</artifactId>
```

and then I use it somewhere like that:

```
<mainClass>${artifactId}</mainClass>
```

But I need to get from `some-usefull-module` the next value `SomeUsefullModule`. Can I do this in Maven pom.xml?

Comment: Sorry can you please describe more in detail what your use case is and why you need such thing? Best with a full example...

Answer (score 0):

The build helper lets you set properties via regex:

https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/regex-property-mojo.html